# Advanced Gantt Chart for SSRS2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, gantt-chart

I have been working in SSRS 2008 r2 to produce some complex reports. it seems to meet 80% of our reporting requirements. However, when it comes down to more complex reports, it turns into some pain in the back side really.

I need to generate a sort of advance Gantt view in SSRS. RangeBar char is suggested to be used for Gantt scenarios. But it did not seem to meet my requirement as I need more customizability .

I was just wondering whether there is any opensource or paid solution for advance gantt reports in ssrs.

I had a deep search on the internet and could not find more interesting really.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any third party plug ins (Surprisingly). However there is an excellent article on this on SQL Server Central:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/Santa+gets+an+RDL+present/61782/

It would take a lot of setting up and uses in built SSRS controls (RangeBar Chart) but it is a free solution. SSRS is a great tool for displaying and manipulating report based information, however it does lack in areas for granularity and customisation.

Comment: @AnarachistGeek - The RDL is downloadable from the link that Darren cites.